# Javascript not working with my Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to use Regular expression in Javascript `split()` method

Target String to run a split method against is:

> type=Search&searchType=simple&searchField=partOne &&
>   partTwo&highlight=partOne&isAllProductsContext=true&isAllProductInstance=false&contextId=&effectivity=

My code:

```
this.regexPattern = new RegExp("((?<=&&)&(?!&))|((?<!&)&(?!&))",'ig');
var keysAndValuesArray = targetString.split(regexPattern);
```

Comment: My code --> this.regexPattern = new RegExp("((?<=&&)&(?!&))|((?<!&)&(?!&))",'ig'); 
var keysAndValuesArray = targetString.split(regexPattern);

Comment: Can you tell us the expected output?

Comment: Problem - I want to split following String 
Target String: type=Search&searchType=simple&searchField=piston && rod&highlight=piston  
into array of string as: 
1.type=Search   2.searchType=simple  3.searchField=piston && rod  4.highlight=piston  
i.e I want to split on '&' in target string, BUT NOT ON '&&' (&& is operator in my string)
Can you please suggest how to do that in javascript ?

Comment: If you are going to use this in URL, I would suggest URL Component encoding `piston && rod`.

Comment: Not really - I'm not using this in URL, I'm using this as string passed to Server in form of Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript regex engine doesn't support [`lookbehind`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as in your regex.

You will need to rewrite your regex to be used in Javascript. If you define your problem clearly we can give you some alternatives.

#### UPDATE Here is Javascript code that can work with OP's requirements:

```
s = 'type=Search&searchType=simple&searchField=partOne && partTwo&highlight=partOne&isAllProductsContext=true&isAllProductInstance=false&contextId=&effectivity=';
m  = s.match(/[^&]+(?:&&[^&]*)?(?=&|$)/g);
```

**OUTPUT:

```
["type=Search", "searchType=simple", "searchField=partOne && partTwo", "highlight=partOne", "isAllProductsContext=true", "isAllProductInstance=false", "contextId=", "effectivity="]
```

Comment: I want to split targetString as - type=Search  &  searchType=simple  &searchField=piston && rod  &highlight=piston  what could be done then ? Need change in Regular Expression ? as this same regex worked fine in my JAVA code but not working in Javscript code. Pls advise

Comment: Because Java regex engine has support of lookbehind but Javascript doesn't support that.

Comment: Problem - I want to split following String 
Target String: type=Search&searchType=simple&searchField=piston && rod&highlight=piston  
into array of string as: 
1.type=Search   2.searchType=simple  3.searchField=piston && rod  4.highlight=piston  
i.e I want to split on '&' in target string, BUT NOT ON '&&' (&& is operator in my string)
Can you please suggest how to do that in javascript using regex ?

Comment: Not match, I want to split. Can this same expression will work for split() ? I'm not sure that it will.

Comment: End result is always an array of strings you are interested in. Looks like you have accepted pretty complex solution for this simple probem, do you still want a modified solution?

Comment: Pls if you can suggest even simpler version of soln, will be great help.

Comment: What I have my answer is pretty simple solution as 1. It's a one linerr 2. There is no loop involved 3. No multiple regex

Comment: Worked like charm for me. Needed some changes but that was for my different requirement. Big Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
targetString.replace(/([^&])&([^&])/g,"$1&&&$2")
            .split("&&&");
```

or match it incase &&& doesn't work for you

```
var match,results = [];
var patt=/(.*?[^&])&(?=[^&])/g;
while (match = patt.exec(str))
   results.push(+match[1]);
```

Comment: This will replace any '#' coming in targetString as well. Not a good idea.

Comment: No Can't take this risk of replacing characters, I'm not sure what user can enter in the form of TargetString.

Comment: if TargetString contains &&& then also it gives problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not split, but match does a similar work

```
var test = 'type=Search&searchType=simple&searchField=partOne && partTwo&highlight=partOne&isAllProductsContext=true&isAllProductInstance=false&contextId=&effectivity=';
var re = /(?:[a-zA-Z]+=(?:(?:[^&]+(?:&&)?)+)(?=&|$))/g;
alert( test.match(re) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
var keysAndValuesArray = targetString.match(/(&\W+|[^&])+/g);
```